# Ruby - Run multiple process and detach

Tags: ruby, process, spawn

I would like to run multiple long running rendering commands from Ruby (2.0.0-p247) on macos. I also need to pass data to the `stdin` of the various processes.

```
point_groups.each_with_index do |points, i|
    cmd = "/usr/local/radiance/bin/rtrace -h -n 4 -ab 0 -oMpd -fff /var/folders/gp/r89xmhrj5_ngq8wtx8hthpqr0000gn/T/shadow_mask.oct > /var/folders/gp/r89xmhrj5_ngq8wtx8hthpqr0000gn/T/sm_#{i}.out"
    puts cmd
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
    stdin.puts points.pack("F*")
    stdin.close
    stdout.close
    stderr.close
    puts wait_thr.value
end
```

Here `point_groups` is an array of array of floats. Each of the elements (array of floats) is packed and sent to the `stdin`.

This approach works, but the processes are executed sequentially.

EDIT (Based on Stefan suggestion)

```
threads = []
point_groups.each_with_index do |points, i|
    cmd = "/usr/local/radiance/bin/rtrace -h -n 4 -ab 0 -oMpd -fff /var/folders/gp/r89xmhrj5_ngq8wtx8hthpqr0000gn/T/shadow_mask.oct > /var/folders/gp/r89xmhrj5_ngq8wtx8hthpqr0000gn/T/sm_#{i}.out"
    puts cmd
    stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen3(cmd)
    threads << wait_thr
    stdin.puts points.pack("F*")
    stdin.close
    stdout.close
    stderr.close
end
threads.each{|thr| thr.join }
```

Unfortunately, it behaves in the same way.

Comment: Calling [`value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Thread.html#method-i-value) waits for the thread to complete. You should put each thread into an array and send them `value` afterwards, i.e. in another loop.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan I have edited my question